# How to expand a loop iterating over an array dynamically in BASH?

Tags: bash

I need to iterate on an array and expand the array while iterating. How do I do it in BASH?

For example:

```
req="a b c d"
read -a MODULES <<<$req

for MODULE_NAME in "${MODULES[@]}"; do
    echo $MODULE_NAME
    if something-happens-only-one-time; then 
        MODULES+=( "e" )
    fi
done
```

I want to get the following output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

## Edit:

Following code works for now:

```
i=0
while true; do
    MODULE_NAME="${MODULES[$i]}"
    echo ${MODULE_NAME}

    if something-happens-only-one-time; then 
        MODULES+=( "e" )
    fi

    i=$((i+1))
    num_of_modules=${#MODULES[@]}
    if (("$i" >= "$num_of_modules")) ; then 
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: You can pipe the array to sort then uniq -u. It will output any members that appear only once. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618378/select-unique-or-distinct-values-from-a-list-in-unix-shell-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work with a `for ... in "${arr[@]}"` loop because `"${arr[@]}"` is evaluated immediately. That is, even though you add elements to it during the loop, the range of the loop is already determined, and won't be affected.

You could rewrite as a counting `for` loop:

```
for ((i = 0; i < "${#MODULES[@]}"; i++)); do
    MODULE_NAME=${MODULES[$i]}
    echo $MODULE_NAME
    if something-happens-only-one-time; then 
        MODULES+=( "e" )
    fi
done
```

This works because `${#MODULES[@]}` in the loop condition is re-evaluated in every loop cycle. So after a value is appended during the loop,
then at the start of the next cycle the value of `${#MODULES[@]}` will be increased by 1.

Comment: Following code doesn't work https://gist.github.com/ceremcem/2f399afef92332bcd5d7b778a1da302d

Comment: @ceremcem you've made some mistakes in there. Here's the fix: https://gist.github.com/janosgyerik/fa5e4b2c342123f9f18d022a02f1ca47